# Cannot add Module to Java EE Enterprise Application - nullPointer when creating Enterprise Application Project

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, build, websphere, rad

We have been using RAD 7.5.5/WebSphere 6.1, but are upgrade our dev environment to Eclipse Juno/WAS 8.5. While everything works in RAD/WAS 6.1, I am having trouble getting our website running locally in Eclipse/WAS 8.5.

I took a screencast of my creation process, see the link below. The `nullPointerException` stack trace is included as well.
http://screencast.com/t/VE5KxmCCSsQ

Here are some images of my project settings. CBSWebApp is the Java/JSP application, and eCB is the Enterprise Application Project.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TFNV.png

```
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Error
Thu Jul 18 15:18:02 EDT 2013


java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.application.internal.operations.AddComponentToEnterpriseApplicationOp.findReferencedComponent(AddComponentToEnterpriseApplicationOp.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.application.internal.operations.AddComponentToEnterpriseApplicationOp.updateEARDD(AddComponentToEnterpriseApplicationOp.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.application.internal.operations.AddComponentToEnterpriseApplicationOp.execute(AddComponentToEnterpriseApplicationOp.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl$1.run(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.doExecute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.executeImpl(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.cacheThreadAndContinue(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.execute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.project.facet.EarFacetPostInstallDelegate.execute(EarFacetPostInstallDelegate.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.events.internal.LegacyEventHandlerAdapter.handleEvent(LegacyEventHandlerAdapter.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.events.internal.ProjectListenerRegistry.notifyListeners(ProjectListenerRegistry.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.notifyListeners(FacetedProject.java:1327)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.modifyInternal(FacetedProject.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.mergeChangesInternal(FacetedProject.java:1181)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.access$2(FacetedProject.java:1117)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject$5.run(FacetedProject.java:1099)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.mergeChanges(FacetedProject.java:1109)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.commitChanges(FacetedProjectWorkingCopy.java:2020)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.ModifyFacetedProjectWizard.performFinish(ModifyFacetedProjectWizard.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.wst.web.ui.internal.wizards.NewProjectDataModelFacetWizard.performFinish(NewProjectDataModelFacetWizard.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.ModifyFacetedProjectWizard$3.run(ModifyFacetedProjectWizard.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui.ModifyFacetedProjectWizard$4.run(ModifyFacetedProjectWizard.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

I also get the below `nullPointerException` when trying to set the context root to `CBSWebApp` in Eclipse. When looking at my settings in the working RAD environment, I noticed this field was successfully filled out as 'CBSWebApp', but remains a blank default in Eclipse, and I cannot change it without generating the below error.

```
null
Error
Thu Jul 18 16:06:44 EDT 2013


java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.resources.VirtualComponent.setMetaProperty(VirtualComponent.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.operation.ServerContextRootUpdateOperation.execute(ServerContextRootUpdateOperation.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl$1.run(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.doExecute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.executeImpl(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.cacheThreadAndContinue(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.execute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.util.ComponentUtilities.setServerContextRoot(ComponentUtilities.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.ui.refactoring.RenameContextRootChange.perform(RenameContextRootChange.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation$1.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.executeChange(PerformChangeOperation.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.UIPerformChangeOperation.executeChange(UIPerformChangeOperation.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.PerformChangeOperation.run(PerformChangeOperation.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.internal.ui.refactoring.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Your help is greatly appreciated in this - this is causing a lot of problems for me and my team. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete the project facet .xml file so I could recreate it with the correct facets

Answer (score 1):

Root cause is that the WTP project configuration fails due to the wrong java web facet being installed.

You could try to determine if the EAR project has deployment descriptor, if so, then force save.

```
    final ReferencedComponent ref = AddComponentToEnterpriseApplicationOp.findReferencedComponent(earwc, wc, se, compse);
```

Comment: Thannks @WEBALDO.at - but I'm not sure how to force a save. How do I make sure the right java web facet is installed?